# How to remove a parent div based on the symbol it has inside?

Tags: c#, html, regex

It is possible to remove the item which has (x) symbol including parent div.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2 id="-663241532">
            <span>Item 1</span>
        </h2>
        <p>Content 1</p>
     </div>
     <div>
         <h4 id="1074494955">
             <span>(x)Item 1.1.1</span>
         </h4>
         <p>Title 2</p>
         <div>
            Content 2
         </div>  
      </div>
</div>
```

After removing it must be

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2 id="-663241532">
            <span>Item 1</span>
        </h2>
        <p>Content 1</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I wrote this regex

```
@"<div>(.*?)<span>\(x\)(.*?)</span>(.*?)</div>"
```

but it removes the first div also.

I have the id -663241532 accessible if it can help.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this, use an HTML/XML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) for working with HTML:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("index.html");
var spans = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[contains(., '(x)')]");
foreach (var span in spans)
{
    HtmlNode parent = span.ParentNode;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        if (parent.Name == "div")
        {
            parent.Remove();
            break;
        }

        parent = parent.ParentNode;
    }
}
```

XPath above selects all `span` nodes which contain `(x)` text. Then in loop we search nearest `div` parent of each selected `span` and remove it.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested regexes are not the best tool for xml document manipulation. Example solution using Linq to XML:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(html);
var spansToRemove = xDoc.Descendants("span")
                        .Where(s => s.Value.StartsWith("(x)")).ToArray();
foreach (var toRemove in spansToRemove)
{
    var element = toRemove;
    while (element != null && element.Name != "div")
        element = element.Parent;
    if (element != null)
        element.Remove();
}
```

Comment: +1 for more compact remove logic, but keep in mind that valid html can be considered as non valid xml

Comment: Agreed, that's why I've upvoted your HtmlAgilityPack answer - great library, saved me quite a few times.